# Error con select2 plugin de php para combo con buscador

Tags: php, javascript

> Buenas, tengo un problema con un plugin de php llamada select2, combo con buscador. Me podrian orientar por favor es la primera vez que utilizo ese plugin.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En la imagen de arriba, muestra el modal con el combo con buscador con tamaño pequeño.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Al escribir en el combo con buscador se agranda y desordena todo el modal.
>
> Mi codigo html

```
<td>CLIENTE: </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="mi-selector" name="xcliente" id="p3" multiple='multiple'>
                                <option value="0">Seleccione...</option>
                                <?php while ($fila = $cliente_0->fetch_array()) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $fila['0']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['2']; ?></option>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('.mi-selector').select2();
                                    });
                                });
                                    </script>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
```

> Los enlaces de las librerias

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Te genera algún error? Por que supongo que podrías arreglarlo estableciendo un tamaño por defecto al `select`.

Comment: Hola, como le agrego el tamaño por defecto. Porque al escribir se agranda.

Comment: Podrías agregarle un estilo con un ancho por defecto al elemento `select`  tal que : `style="width: 100px; max-width: 100px;"`

Comment: Gracias ya solucione el tamaño, pero tengo un problema en el select esta esto multiple='multiple' , si lo quito, mi buscador adentro del combo no funciona. No debe tener multiple.

Comment: El atributo `multiple` solo altera el comportamiento de la selección de los valores, realmente no debería haber problema con la búsqueda. Intenta inicializar el control `select2` envolviéndolo dentro de una sola función `ready` de jquery como se especifica en la documentación https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage.